# Image displayed locally but not displayed on the server

Tags: node.js, angular, express, nginx, multer

I am using (nodejs, express, multer) & Angular. I am successfully uploading and opening a photo locally, but on the virtual server the photo is uploading but not showing up in the UI.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwITZ.png)

Comment: We are going to need some code snippets and more info to help you.

Comment: I solved this problem by correctly specifying the root folder in the nginx settings.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have all the photos under the folders /public/uploads/images/
in nginx (/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default)
i added these lines
location /public/uploads/images/ {
root/backend;
}
and problem solved)